# Calculating $\iiint_{I} \frac{2z}{(x+y)^2}dx~ dy ~dz$, $I:=[1,2] \times [2,3] \times [0,2]$ using substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to calculate $\iiint_{I} \frac{2z}{(x+y)^2}dx~ dy ~dz$, $I:=[1,2] \times [2,3] \times [0,2]$

$$\int_1^2 \int_2^3 \int_0^2 \frac{2z}{(x+y)^2}~dx~ dy ~dz = \cdots$$

My idea is to substitute $x+y$, but  i'm very unsure, how to continue, especially what the bounds of integration are..

Comment: $z$ goes from $0$ to $2$, right? So I think you should have the $[0,2]$ integral sign on the left, matching the $dz$ on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, then substitute.

$$\int_1^2 \int_2^3 \int_0^2 \frac{2z}{(x+y)^2}dxdydz$$

$$u=x+y\implies dx=du$$

So the integral ranges from $y$ to $y+2$. Then we have

$$\int_1^2 \int_2^3 \int _y^{y+2} \frac{2z}{u^2}dudydz$$

Then, doing the first integral:

$$\int_1^2 \int_2^3 \bigg[-\frac{2z}{u}\bigg]_y^{y+2}dydz=\int_1^2\int_2^3-\frac{2z}{y+2}+\frac{2z}{y} dy dz$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Since $y,z$ are held fixed in the integration go ahead, proceed naturally.